# Would it be correct to say that viruses are genotoxic?

Tags: genetics, virology

I know it is an unconventional way to describe viruses, but would it still be technically correct?

Answer (score 3):

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genotoxicity)

> In genetics, genotoxicity describes the property of chemical agents that damages the genetic information within a cell causing mutations

While some viruses tend to cause mutations, most don't have such a strong mutagenesis effect. As such, they are not really genotoxic. Also, even if a virus is genotoxic, one should definitely not reduce the activity of a virus to its genotoxicity. A virus has a life-cycle and is able to reproduce. It is clearly more than a simple genotoxic chemical agent such as metal chromium.

So, in short

1. Reducing viruses to their genotoxic effect would be a misrepretentation of what virsues are
2. Most viruses don't have a strong genotoxic effect and therefore you can not make the claim in the general sense.